# Get column name based on cell

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I would like to get in column `A2:A`, the names of columns `B1:D1` separated by commas, if the row contains data. As in the screenshot:
[image]

I found this formula: `=TEXTJOIN(", ",true,BYCOL(B1:D,LAMBDA(c,IFNA(IF(MATCH("?*",c,0),INDEX(c,1),""),""))))`
But it takes data from all rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try `ARRAYFORMULA` from [Google Sheets.](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093275?hl=en)

Example;

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TEXTJOIN(", ", TRUE, IF(B2:D<>"", B1:D1, "")))
```

From the above code, this `ARRAYFORMULA` performs an array operation in the specified cell range. Then `IF` is used to check a cell in the row contains data. If have data, the column name is added to the result. If none, it is ignored.

Answer (score 0):

*You may try:*

```js
=byrow(indirect("B2:"&rows(A:A)),lambda(Σ,if(counta(Σ)=0,,join(", ",filter(B1:1,Σ="q")))))
```

[image]